# htaccess rewrite rule for a part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to change over htaccess from

```
http://www.mydomain.com/pictures/generated/product/1/280_280_75/nopic.jpg
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/pictures/generated/product/1/280_280_75/nopic1.jpg
```

Here is my rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule nopic\.jpg$ nopic1\.jpg
```

It works in some way;) The whole URL will be changed just to "nopic1.jpg".

The question is: How can I change only the last part of URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)nopic\.jpg$ $1nopic1\.jpg
```