# Trying to rewrite part of url through Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite some part of my URL, and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried following this [Other Stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106561/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-a-part-of-url-solved)

This is how I want to rewrite my URL

```
http://localhost/job/test-job/
```

to

```
http://localhost/jobs/test-job/
```

This is how my RewriteRule looks right now

```
RewriteRule ^job/(.*)$ jobs/$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Delete (.htaccess) file , then see if it work ,because I think .htaccess file not work in localhost server ----- [imgzero](http://www.imgzero.com/)

Comment: Whoops, switched the examples around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar on my website. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?job/(.*)$ /jobs/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Sometimes the URL comes through with a leading slash, sometimes without. The `/?` handles that.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Also, it seems that if you don't be sure to remove the cache of the browser when testing the .htaccess, weird things starts to happend.

Comment: Yes: 301 is a permanent redirect, so the browser will cache that, and not even request the original URL any more, as long as it's in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^job/(.*)$ /jobs/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can test it with [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Whoops! I made a mistake in the examples, its the other way around! I want "job" to become "jobs"

Comment: Well, can you check updated answer? And are you sure that you are using my rewrite rule? It's almost idenctical to your, but you've missed to specify the index of matched string at the end.